# Android - recyclerAdapter.getItem returns null in the onClick callback

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

How could this be possible?

The adapter uses the position to bind the view holder, so the user can see the item view on the screen.

But then the user clicks the item which causes a NullPointerException due to the getItem(position) returns null.

Is there something wrong with my implementation?

The adapter:

```
// There will be more than 1000 items, so the SparseArray will face the performance problem. That's why I choose to use Map.
private Map<Integer, ArticleBean> articleBeans;
private Map<Integer, Integer> articleSerials = new LinkedHashMap<>();

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    ArticleBean articleBean = articleBeans.get(position);
}

public ArticleBean getItem(int position){
    return articleBeans.get( position );
}

public void addItem(ArticleBean articleBean){
    if( !articleSerials.containsKey(serial) ){
        articleSerials.put( serial, articleBeans.size() );
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
    articleBeans.put( articleBeans.size(), articleBean );
}
```

The onClick callback:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    // returns null
    ArticleBean articleBean = mAdapter.getItem( position );
}
```

I mean, if the user could click the item, how would it be null?

Answer (score 1):

This problem only occurs while the user is using pullToRefresh feature and click the item at the same time.

The `onRefresh` will be called after the animation end. And I clear my dataSet and call `notifyDataSetChanged` of the recyclerAdapter in this method.
But the `notifyDataSetChanged` is an asycTask, so do the `onRefresh`.
If the dataSet has been cleared but the view has not been refreshed, the `NullPointerException` will be thrown when user clicks the item.

So all I have to do is to add this line into the `onClick` method to make sure the dataSet is not empty.

```
if( mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ) return;
```